# Java calling bash script : Permission Denied Error

Tags: java, linux, unix

I am trying to call a bash script from a java class .

This is my java program

```
import java.io.File;

public class RunBuild {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File wd = new File("/home/sai/Jan5WS/ATCore/bin/");
        System.out.println("Working Directory: " + wd);
        Process proc = null;
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" . Ram.sh", null, wd);
            System.out.println(proc.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have got all the permissions for that script , please see below
    sai@sai-Aspire-4720Z:~/Jan5WS/ATCore/bin$ chmod 7777 Ram.sh

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sai sai    77 Feb  3 20:53 Ram.sh~
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sai sai    79 Feb  3 20:53 Ram.sh
sai@sai-Aspire-4720Z:~/Jan5WS/ATCore/bin$
```

Its throwing this exception below

```
Working Directory: /home/sai/Jan5WS/ATCore/bin
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "." (in directory
"/home/sai/Jan5WS/ATCore/bin"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at RunBuild.main(RunBuild.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

I am using Ubuntu 
Please let me know what could be the problem ??

Answer (score 3):

See your error output - you are trying to execute `"."` which is a directory, not your shell script:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "."
```

Replace the `" . "` in your `exec()` call with `"./"` to indicate the current directory, make sure that your script has the proper shebang line, like `#!/bin/bash`, and that it is executable (which you already did):

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./Ram.sh", null, wd);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how the `exec` function call works in Java, I really doubt it will run a shell and accept shell commands. And the command you want to execute is `.` which is an internal BASH alias for the `source` command.

You have to call a shell explicitly instead:

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c Ram.sh", null, wd);
```