# Permission denied when running shell script from java program

Tags: java, shell

I am trying to run my shell script using java program. I am getting following exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/builder/code/target/classes/idFetcher.sh": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:605)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:443)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:340)
    at script.InformationFetcher.main(InformationFetcher.java:26)
```

The path of file is correct and file is present at that location. Here is my code

```
package script;

import java.io.IOException;

public class InformationFetcher {

    public InformationFetcher() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InformationFetcher informationFetcher = new InformationFetcher();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(informationFetcher.getFilePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    public String getFilePath() {
    return this.getClass().getResource("/idFetcher.sh").getPath();
    }

}
```

Comment: This should help. I think, you have a similar issue. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684713/java-calling-bash-script-permission-denied-error

Comment: Make sure your shell script has the right execute permission for owner , group, and global.

Comment: chmod +x might help...

Comment: Thank you everyone. It was a permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the shell script executable for the user