# Execute bash script in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bash

I'm trying to figure out how to execute a simple bash script from a JAVA program inside eclipse. I have already checked some questions like [Cannot run program "..../abc.exe": error=13, Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436972/cannot-run-program-abc-exe-error-13-permission-denied) and [Permission denied when running shell script from java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789957/permission-denied-when-running-shell-script-from-java-program), but still I have this error:

> IOException: Cannot run program "prog" error=13, Permission denied.

I have already checked file permissions:

> -rwxrwxr-x user user prog

I use this snippet to execute the script:

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("prog").getFile());
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());
try {
  Process process = processBuilder.start();
  process.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Where is this script? It looks like you may have it inside a jar - objects in a jar are not files and you can't access them using `File`.

Comment: It is inside the resources folder of my eclipse projects. The file is a bash script which calls some jars on which I have no control. If I call it via terminal it works perfectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When invoking bash scripts from java you must specify '/bin/bash' as the executable and pass your script path as an argument.

Comment: I tried in the following manner: 'ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", file.getAbsolutePath());' and the script gets executed. Thanks for the help.