# Eclipse Run External Tools error=13, Permission denied

Tags: eclipse, file-permissions, permission-denied

I am attempting to run a bash .sh script within my Eclipse project (i.e., Run->External Tools).

> Exception occurred executing command line.
>   Cannot run program "/media/datashare/Dropbox/Programming>/ProgramCode/MetaDB_text_menu/meta-db/spinup_systems.sh": >error=13, Permission denied

I believe my permissions are set correctly:

> -rwxrwxr-x 1 brian fuse   947 Nov 22 13:04 spinup_systems.sh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute bash script in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660512/execute-bash-script-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse -> Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration

From [Execute bash script in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660512/execute-bash-script-in-eclipse) :
When invoking bash scripts...you must specify '/bin/bash' as the executable and pass your script path as an argument.

> Location: /bin/bash
>
> Arguments: ${workspace_loc:/MetaDB_text_menu/meta-db/spinup_systems.sh}

[image]

Comment: If you agree it's a duplicate, you can just accept the duplicate flag and close the question, rather than copying the answer from the duplicate link...

Comment: I appreciate the similarity of the solution, but I would not consider this a duplicate. I had read the other answer prior to posting (it did not help me). From my perspective, this post is a more direct question and answer to the problem I encountered.